# Spring not roll back transaction if exception throws in the application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-transactions

I developed the application using spring transactions and insert records in the table.

I'm explicitly throwing the exception in DAO class but spring is inserting the record into the table rather than roll back the transaction.

I have created the two applications as below . In Case 1 record is inserted into table even though exception is thrown . But In Case 2 no record is inserted and spring roll back the transaction successfully. Can you explain me the difference between these two applications.

Case 1:

Item.java

```
public class Item {

    int itemNo;
    String itemName;
    String itemType;
    String itemSize;
    public int getItemNo() {
        return itemNo;
    }
    public void setItemNo(int itemNo) {
        this.itemNo = itemNo;
    }
    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }
    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }
    public String getItemType() {
        return itemType;
    }
    public void setItemType(String itemType) {
        this.itemType = itemType;
    }
    public String getItemSize() {
        return itemSize;
    }
    public void setItemSize(String itemSize) {
        this.itemSize = itemSize;
    }
}
```

ItemDao

```
@Service
public class ItemDao {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate ;


    void insert(Item item){

        jdbcTemplate.update("insert into item_test(itemno, itemtype,itemsize,itemname) values (?,?,?,?)", new Object[]{item.getItemNo(),item.getItemType(),item.getItemSize(),item.getItemName()});
        int a=2/0;
    }
}
```

ItemService.java

```
@Service
public class ItemService {
    @Autowired
    ItemDao itemDao;    


    @Transactional
    public void insert(Item item){
        try{
            itemDao.insert(item);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Test.java

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ApplicationContext ct = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        ItemService itemService = ct.getBean("itemService", ItemService.class);

        Item item = new Item();
        item.setItemNo(1234);
        item.setItemName("sofa");
        item.setItemSize("4");
        item.setItemType("furniture");
        itemService.insert(item);
    }

}
```

spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
    <!-- Enable Annotation based Declarative Transaction Management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.springtransaction" />
    <!-- Creating TransactionManager Bean, since JDBC we are creating of type 
        DataSourceTransactionManager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
    <!-- MySQL DB DataSource -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@locahost:1521:xe)))" />
        <property name="username" value="system" />
        <property name="password" value="system" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="itemService" class="com.spring.springtransaction.ItemService" />
</beans>
```

Case 2:

ItemService.java

```
@Service
public class ItemService {
    @Autowired
    ItemDao itemDao;

    @Autowired
    ItemManger itemManger;

    @Transactional
    public void insert(Item item){
        try{
            itemManger.insert(item);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

ItemManger.java

```
@Service
public class ItemManger {

    @Autowired
    ItemDao itemDao;


    @Transactional
    public void insert(Item item){

        itemDao.insert(item);

    }
}
```

ItemDao.java

```
@Service
public class ItemDao {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate ;


    void insert(Item item){

        jdbcTemplate.update("insert into item_test(itemno, itemtype,itemsize,itemname) values (?,?,?,?)", new Object[]{item.getItemNo(),item.getItemType(),item.getItemSize(),item.getItemName()});
        int a=2/0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Annotate you `ItemDao` as `@Repository`  instead of `@Service`

Comment: I have updated with same no change

Comment: You should execute unit test with spring context instead of main

Comment: Case 1: no exception is ever thrown from a transactional method, since you catch it inside. So nothing is rollbacked. Case 2: an exception is thrown from a transactional method, so it's rollbacked.

Comment: in both cases exception is thrown from DAO class

Comment: But your DAO is not transactional. In case 2, the transaction is also thrown from the ItemManger, which is transactional, so the transactional proxy around it sees that an exception is thrown, and marks the transaction for rollback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate you `ItemDao` as `@Repository` instead of `@Service`

You should execute unit test with spring **Transactional** context instead of main , for example using TestNG:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ConfigurationClass.class})
@ActiveProfiles({"test"})
public class TestItemDAO extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {
    @Autowired
    private ItemDao dao;
    @Test
    public void testItemDao() {
        dao.insert(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: The only change i did in Case 2 is i created new service and from that service I am inserting data into the table. But in case 1 I am directly calling Dao class and trying to insert data into the table

Comment: @user3094331 if you want to rollabck just don't catch exceptions

Comment: In both cases I am catching the exception .But what is the difference between them.In case 1 i observed that  proxy class is creating for ItemService only.  But in case 2 proxy classes are creating for both itemService and ItemManger

Comment: `ItemManger` isn't catching exception and is marked as `Trasactional`,meaning will do a rollback

Comment: In case 1 I applied @Transactional on insert method of InsertDao . and throwing exception and not catching  exception .As u mentioned it should roll back. but it is not roll back the transaction

Comment: In case 1: I annotated  Transactional annotation on insert() method  of ItemDao. but the record is inserted in table. In case 2 : also i I annotated  Transactional annotation  on insert() method  of ItemDao. but here transactional is rolled back

Answer (score 0):

Remove the try block, you are trying to handle the exception so this is reason why RollbackException is not cutting the transaction stream.